# Нужно установить цвет конкретно изображению внутри div не задевая пустой участок вокруг

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть  с картинкой двери, который находится поверх фона. Нужно, чтобы при наведении на дверь конкретно изображение двери окрашивалось в другой цвет. При использовании background-color красный появляется в пустой области вокруг неё. Немного похожий эффект, на тот который мне нужен даёт свойство filter, но там нет возможности выбрать нужный цвет. Буду рад любым идеям.
[image: Изображение с проблемой]

Comment: Есть идея с добавлением нескольких одинаковых картинок с нужными цветами и заменой картинки при наведении, но возможно есть способы получше..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, добавить изображению `clip-path`. И работать уже с "усеченным" по определенной геометрии изображением. Почитать - [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/maskirovanie-v-css).